# printf function behaviour and casting

Tags: c, linux

I want to know why printf is giving me some fixed value for every run.
My code is below, please help me to understand.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    float i=10.25,a=5.25;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
    }
```

It is returning 11010048

I know that %f is for float and for printing the float number i must use %f but here the question is why %d is returning the constant value, either it should return some garbage value or it should be compile error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `%d` is or integers, use `%f` for floating point.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: I know that this is mismatch but the return value is not garbage value it is always constant.

Comment: Dan I think you didn't understand the question, question is why %d is giving me this constant value either it should give compile error or garbage value.

Comment: You **are** getting garbage, it just happens to be the same garbage.

Comment: "either it should return some garbage value or it should be compile error." --> No.  A compliant C compiler is not limited to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile this with `-Wall -Wextra`, you'll get the following output:

```
x1.c:5:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d\n",a);
              ^
```

Because `printf` is a variadic function, you are allowed by the language to pass any number of variables of any type after the format string.  The function however does not allow it in this case due to the mismatched format specifier.  So the compiler is not required to emit a diagnostic, but in this case it will if you turn up the warnings.

As to why you keep getting the same value instead of "garbage", getting the wrong value **is** garbage.  There's nothing that says the result should be either consistent or inconsistent.  That's one of the ways [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) manifests itself.

Comment: Any further complaints should be filed under "I am unhappy with the behavior of undefined behavior"

Answer (score 0):

you cant print float with %d, u should try %f

%d is Signed decimal integer

try this

`printf("%f\n,a);`

i suggest u to look via this link:
[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)